# submit function not working?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Below. have an AJAX call, that pulls in .php file to check persons ip and show them form, when submitted the form should then activate. Second AJAX call to submit the data. However, it seems that the second function is not being activated when submit button is clicked, preferably want to call the formSubmit function on success the first AJAX call and onclick activate that function:

```
module.exports = {
  init: function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/microsub.php",
    method: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
      if (data == 1) {
        $('#rdm-below-header').append('<div id=\"modal\" class=\"modalStyle\">' +
              '<div>' +
              '<button type=\"button\" id=\"close\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"modal\" aria-label=\"close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><br>' +
              '<div id=\"titleText\" style=\" text-align:center; font-size: 24px; margin-top: 15px;\">Fill in your details for 24hr access to Risk.net</div><br>' +
              '<form style="text-align:center; clear:both" id="microsubs_form">' +
              '<input type=\"text\" id=\"ms_firstName\" name=\"ms_firstName\" required placeholder=\"First Name\" style=\"float:left;\" >' +
              '<input type=\"text\" id=\"ms_lastName\" name=\"ms_lastName\" required style=\"float:left; margin-left:20px;\" placeholder=\"Last Name\">' +
              '<input type=\"email\" id=\"ms_email\" name=\"ms_email\" required placeholder=\"Corporate Email address\" pattern=\"^.*(\*barclays|\*barcap.com).*$\" oninvalid=\"this.setCustomValidity(\'Please enter your corporate email\')\" style=\"float:left; margin-top: 10px;\">' +
              '<input type=\"password\" id=\"ms_password\" name=\"ms_password\" required style=\"clear:right; margin-top: 10px; margin-left: 20px;\" placeholder=\"Password\" pattern=\".{6,}\">' +
              '<input type=\"text\" id=\"microsub_flag\" name=\"microsub_flag\" hidden=\"true\">' +
              '<input type=\"submit\"  name=\"submit\" style=\"alignment-adjust:central; margin-top:30px; clear:right;\" class=\"msProcess\" id=\"submit\" onclick=\"formSubmit()\"><br>' +
              '</form>' +
              '<div style=\"text-align:center; clear: both; font-size: 16px; margin-top: 5px; \"><br>' +
              'If you already have a subscription, <a href=\"login\">sign in here.</a>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>' +
              '</div>');
      }
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  //Display IP Form

  //On Submit form via AJAX

  // Bind to the submit event of our form
  function formSubmit() {
    $("#microsubs_form").submit(function (event) {
      var request;
      // Abort any pending request
      if (request) {
          request.abort();
      }
      // setup some local variables
      var $form = $(this);
      // Let's select and cache all the fields
      var $inputs = $form.find("input, select, button, textarea");
      // Serialize the data in the form
      var serializedData = $form.serialize();
      // Let's disable the inputs for the duration of the Ajax request.
      // Note: we disable elements AFTER the form data has been serialized.
      // Disabled form elements will not be serialized.
      $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
      // Fire off the request to /form.php
      request = $.ajax({
        url: "/ms_form_handler.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: serializedData,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
      // Prevent default posting of form
      event.preventDefault();
    });
  }
  ;
}};
//On Success Hide form, show success message ask to login
//Set cookie to hide the form
//utility.setCookie(name);
```

Comment: probably your `$('#micro_subs_form')` is being executed when that dom ID doesn't exist yet, so there's nothing for the submit call to actually submit.

Comment: Marc B, even if after the event is created and i submit via .on() i.e ("msProcess")on('click', 'submit', function(event){})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind event when the first ajax complete. Try to add

```
formSubmit();
```

in the success function in the first ajax call.